How should ARPACK be called within an openmp-parallelized for loop?
I have a fortran function that solves an eigenproblem using ARPACK. I am trying to use this function in a parallel context. The function is called from a C file.
I was hoping this would work:
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i=0; i < N; i++)
{
    double *var1 ... ;
    my_arpack_function(var1 ...); // Function call, with only vars local to the block passed
}

the function itself is not parallelized, but each thread makes their own call to the function. I was hoping this would work but it fails.
The following works, though eliminates any benefits of paralellization
#pragma omp parallel for ordered
for (int i=0; i < N; i++)
{
    double *var1 ... ;
    #pragma omp ordered
    {
        my_arpack_function(var1 ...); // Function call, with only vars local to the block passed
    }    
}

It is known that ARPACK is not thread-safe, which is likely the reason for this failure. Is there any way I can force a private instance of all variables used by the function?

"The following works, though eliminates any benefits of paralellization" This is normal because all calls needs to be done serially because the function is not thread safe. Moreover, omp ordered can add a significant overhead due to the order contraint. If you do not care about the order, then you can use omp critical. If the order matters and you do not have much more computation besides this, then you cannot really parallelize this.

"Is there any way I can force a private instance of all variables used by the function?" If the function is compiled separately, this is not possible using multiple threads. You can run multiple processes as a workaround but this can make things significantly more complex regarding what the function does (and introduce side effects). For example, multiprocessing requires to share/send data between processes. Moreover, a potential initialization will be done N times for N processes. A simple way to do multiprocessing computations is to use MPI (standard for scientific computing).
